# Identifying a dateformat and change it into another

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I am working with the following piece of data which has a different format of dates and which creates confusion later in the process. The data is like:

```html
S. No        DateTime               Area 
1         03/05/2019 6:33            A
2         06/03/2019 07:23:45 AM     B
```

The first row is the format %m/%d/%Y h: mm and the second row is the format of %d/%m/%Y hh:mm: ss AM/PM. The first date value can be confusing though, is it 5th march or 3rd May. So to make everything of the same format, I want that my code detects the date format and changes in the desired format.

I have tried doing this:

```
df['Detection Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Detection Date & Time'], errors = 'coerce').dt.datetime
col = df['Detection Date'].apply(str)


for i in df.index:
    if datetime.datetime.strptime(col, '%m/%d/%Y h:mm'):
       ColDate = datetime.datetime.strftime(col, '%d/%m/%Y hh:mm:ss AM/PM')
```

But i am getting an error saying:

```py
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series
```

How it should be conducted.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify both possible `format`s in [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), so if format not match is returned missing values, so is possible use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
date1 = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'], errors = 'coerce', format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
date2 = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'], errors = 'coerce', format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S %p')

df['DateTime'] = date1.fillna(date2)
print (df)
   S. No            DateTime Area
0      1 2019-03-05 06:33:00    A
1      2 2019-03-06 07:23:45    B
```

Last if want specify new format add [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) - advanatage of solution are verify both formats:

```
df['DateTime'] = date1.fillna(date2).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S %p')
print (df)
   S. No                DateTime Area
0      1  05/03/2019 06:33:00 AM    A
1      2  06/03/2019 07:23:45 AM    B
```

**Details**:

```
print (date1)
0   2019-03-05 06:33:00
1                   NaT
Name: DateTime, dtype: datetime64[ns]

print (date2)
0                   NaT
1   2019-03-06 07:23:45
Name: DateTime, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Another possible solution without verify another formats - only repalaced format `%m/%d/%Y %H:%M` to `%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S %p`:

```
date1 = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'], errors = 'coerce', format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M').dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S %p')

df['DateTime'] = date1.replace('NaT', df['DateTime'])
print (df)
   S. No                DateTime Area
0      1  05/03/2019 06:33:00 AM    A
1      2  06/03/2019 07:23:45 AM    B
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael the datetime format, in the end, is %Y-%m-%d %H:%M%S. I would like the format to be %d/%m/%Y %H:%M%S %p.

Answer (score 2):

If it is ok to install a dependency then you can use `dateparser` [link](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

```
import pandas as pd 
import dateparser

df = pd.DataFrame({'Detection Date & Time': ['03/05/2019 6:33', '06/03/2019 07:23:45 AM']}) 
df['Date & time'] =  df['Detection Date & Time'].apply(dateparser.parse)
```

Comment: In the first line, where you specify both the dates, can we parse a column of a data frame containing the dates.?